# How to create multiple USE statements in sniff

Tags: phpcodesniffer

I'm working on a sniff for PHP_CodeSniffer 3.x. For example, the class declaration `class NoInlineFullyQualifiedClassNameUnitTestInc extends \PSR2R\Base\AbstractBase` should be split into a `uses` and `class AbstractBase`. The sniff detects similar issues for method signatures.

I believe the problem is that I'm generating and inserting multiple `use` statements at the same line (i.e., same token), but doing so in separate `fixer->beginChangeset()` ... `fixer->endChangeset()` sequences. The fixer treats multiple sets of changes to the same token as a conflict, and things get messy (and wrong).

The GitHub issue is here: https://github.com/php-fig-rectified/psr2r-sniffer/issues/9

Has anyone figured out how to do this writing custom sniffs for the latest 3.x CodeSniffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is multiple Sniffer (fixer) changesets editing the same token. I was able to get the Sniff to work by collecting a list of USE statements and inserting them at the end of the Sniff's processing.

I identified the end of processing by searching backwards from the last token to find the first token of the list of registered tokens.

**Edit:** Here is the sniff: https://github.com/php-fig-rectified/psr2r-sniffer/blob/master/PSR2R/Sniffs/Namespaces/NoInlineFullyQualifiedClassNameSniff.php

Comment: Could you link the sniff?

Comment: @TomášVotruba I edited the answer to provide the link. Good idea; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `SlevomatCodingStandard\Sniffs\Namespaces\ReferenceUsedNamesOnlySniff`

#### It turns this

[image: Before fixing]

#### Into this

[image: After fixing]

---

### How to use it?

The best is to use it with [EasyCodingStandard](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/03/combine-power-of-php-code-sniffer-and-php-cs-fixer-in-3-lines/) like this:

```
# easy-coding-standard.neon
checkers:
    - SlevomatCodingStandard\Sniffs\Namespaces\ReferenceUsedNamesOnlySniff
```

Install it:

```
composer require --dev symplify\easy-coding-standard
```

Run it:

```
vendor/bin/ecs check src
```

Fix it:

```
vendor/bin/ecs check src --fix
```

**Enjoy and let me know how it works for you.**

If any troubles come up, just [create an issue here](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/issues). I'm happy to improve this tool as much as possible.